# Compressed disk image on Linux

Tags: linux, compression, archiving, disk-image

I just got my new computer with a much bigger harddisk. I think I copied all important files over but just to be sure, I'd like to keep a disk image of my old disk. To save space, I'd like to compress it but I didn't find an option to mount a compressed image.

My goals:

- Result must be easy to access
- No need to decompress the whole thing before I can access anything
- Files should be quick to locate - no TAR/CPIO archive
- Necessary space should be less than just copying the files over

So ideally, I'm looking for a read-only, compressed file system which I can create in a file and which grows automatically.

Comment: Check qcow2. It might be some work to get a qcow2 disk mounted but it is a stable solution with real time compression.

Answer (score 1):

Use a forensic analysis software like [GUYMAGER](http://guymager.sourceforge.net/) (open source, sourceforge.net). It has a nice UI which allows to quickly create a compressed disk image of an entire hard disk.

Use "Advanced forensic image (.aff)" This creates a single, compressed file (well, it also creates an .info file).

To modify the default compression rate 1 (fastest, but least compression). If you have a fast computer with lots of cores, you can change this by creating `/etc/guymager/local.cfg`:

```
AffCompression = 3
```

`9` is the best but slowest compression. `3` gives a good compression with good performance.

**Update**

Mounting isn't as simple as it seems. First of all, you need [AFFLIB](http://afflib.org/) (Ubuntu: `aptitude install afflib-tools`). Now you can get the raw disk image with `[affuse][3] <image> <mount-point>`

But for some reason, mounting the raw image fails. `parted` says the first partition starts with `1048576B` but

```
mount -t ext4 -o loop,ro,offset=1048576 /mnt/backup.raw /mnt/backup
```

fails with the usual useless mount error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

and `dmesg` says:

```
EXT4-fs (loop0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

Answer (score 0):

As Matthias Krull suggests in the comment above, qcow2 can be a good format which supports compression to store a disk image in. It will be supported for quite a while as its the format for QEMU virtual machine disk images. Here's an example command that compresses `/dev/sda` to the compressed image file `sda.qcow2`. By default zlib compression is used, but I think zstd may have a better compression ratio. 8 threads are used to increase throughput, but you should change that to the number of processor cores you have.

```
qemu-img convert -c -p -S 512 -o compression_type=zstd" -f raw -O qcow2 -m 8 \
  /dev/sda sda.qcow2
```

Access the image as a readonly block device NBD, Network Block device, can be used, as follows:

```
modprobe nbd
qemu-nbd -r -c /dev/nbd0 sda.qcow2
kpartx -av /dev/nbd0
```

Then the file system can be mounted as normal using `mount` and the appropriate device in `/dev/mapper`.

Answer (score 0):

For file systems that support block compression, one option is to use store the disk image directly as a file. I know that BTRFS supports this, but likely others too. In the case of BTRFS, you will likely need to enable the mount option `compress-force` to override the uncompressible heuristic. You'll also want to create a sparse file. This can be done with `dd`, as in this example:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/mount/btrfs/sda.img conv=sparse,fsync iflag=nocache oflag=nocache
```

This will create a sparse file, so zero sectors will not take up space, and BTRFS will compress blocks that are compressible (assuming you did turn that on). The `compsize` tool can be used to see how much the file is compressed. Using `du` will only show the size of the uncompressed file minus holes, so will not be accurate.

To mount any file systems in the image, the following can be used:

```
LOOPDEV=$(losetup --show -f /mount/btrfs/sda.img)
kpartx -av "$LOOPDEV"
mount /dev/mapper/"$LOOPDEV"p3 # To mount the 3rd partition
```

If you do not use a file system that has native compression, eg. `ext4`, you can still use this method, by wrapping the disk image in a BTRFS file system image. That could look like this:

```
truncate -s 100G backup-sda.btrfs.img
mkfs.btrfs backup-sda.btrfs.img
mount -o compress-force=zstd:9 backup-sda.btrfs.img /media/tmp
cd /media/tmp
# Now do commands to create disk image as above
```

This method allows more control over the compression algorithms and compress level than the method using `qemu-img convert`, which only allows the selection of compression method, not level, and has less available compression methods.